# Received "no route to host exception" connecting to a host with an IPv6 Address in Java

Tags: java, sockets, ipv6

getting the "no route to host exception" when trying to connect to a IPv6 address in Java . Using the simple Java code to connect like below

```
socket = new Socket();
 SocketAddress serverAddress = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);
 socket.connect(serverAddress, timedout);
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that you don't have IPv6 configuration on your computer. To check that, try connecting to `::0` (Loopback) it should work even without any configurations.

If you want to use addresses other than `::0`, you should find an ISP that support it or just configure a LAN between two or more computers (or VMs).